# Why ZeroMQ fails to communicate when I use multiprocessing.Process to run?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, zeromq, pyzmq

please see the code below :

---

*`server.py`*

```
import zmq 
import time
from multiprocessing import Process
class A:
  def __init__(self):
    ctx = zmq.Context(1)
    sock = zmq.Socket(ctx, zmq.PUB)
    sock.bind('ipc://test')
    p = Process(target=A.run, args=(sock,))
    p.start()     # Process calls run, but the client can't receive messages
    p.join()      #
    #A.run(sock)  # this one is ok, messages get it to be received

  @staticmethod
  def run(sock):
    while True:
      sock.send('demo'.encode('utf-8'))
      print('sent')
      time.sleep(1)

if __name__ =='__main__':
  a = A()
```

---

*`client.py`*

```
import zmq 
ctx=zmq.Context(1)
sock = zmq.Socket(ctx, zmq.SUB)
sock.connect('ipc://test')
sock.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '') 
while True:
  print(sock.recv())
```

In the constructor of `server.py`, if I call `.run()`-method directly, the client can receive the message, but when I use the `multiprocessing.Process()`-method, it fails. Can anyone explain on this and provide some advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Q** : *"Why ZeroMQ fails to communicate when I use `multiprocessing.Process` to run?"*

Well, ZeroMQ does not fail to communicate, the problem is, how Python `multiprocessing` module "operates".

The module is designed so that some processing may escape from the python central GIL-lock (re-`[SERIAL]`-iser, that is used as a forever present `[CONCURRENT]`-situations' **principal *avoider***).

This means that the call to the `multiprocessing.Process` makes one exact "mirror-copy" of the python interpreter state, "exported" into new O/S-spawned process (details depend on localhost O/S).

Given that, there is zero chance a "mirror"-ed replica could get access to resources already owned by the `__main__` - here the `.bind()`-method already acquired `ipc://test` address, so "remote"-process will never get "permission" to touch this ZeroMQ AccessPoint, unless the code gets repaired & fully re-factored.

> **Q** : *"Can anyone explain on this and provide some advice?"*

Sure. The best step to start is to fully understand Pythonic culture of monopolistic GIL-lock re-`[SERIAL]`-isation, where no two things ever happen in the same time, so even adding more threads does not speed-up the flow of the processing, as it all gets re-aligned by the central "monopolist" The GIL-lock.

Next, understanding a promise of a fully reflected copy of the python interpreter state, while it sounds promising, also has some obvious drawbacks - the new processes, being "mirror"-copies cannot introduce colliding cases on already owned resources. If they try to, a *not working as expected* cases are the milder of the problems in such principally ill-designed cases.

In your code, the first row in `__main__` instantiates `a = A()`, where `A`'s `.__init__` method straight occupies the IPC-resource since `.bind('ipc://test')`. The later step, `p = Process( target = A.run, args = ( sock, ) )` "mirror"-replicates the state of the python interpreter (an as-is copy) and the `p.start()` cannot but crash into disability to "own" the same resource as the `__main__` already owns (yes, the `ipc://test` for a "mirror"-ed process instructed call to grab the same, non-free resource in `.bind('ipc://test')` ). This will never fly.

Last but not least, enjoy the Zen-of-Zero, the masterpiece of Martin SUSTRIK for [distributed-computing](/questions/tagged/distributed-computing), so well crafted for ultimately scalable, almost zero-latency, very comfortable, widely ported signalling & messaging framework.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Start your subprocesses. Create your `zmq.Context`- and `.Socket`-instances from within your `Producer.run()`-classmethod *within each subprocess*. Use `.bind()`-method on the side on which your cardinality is 1, and `.connect()`-method on the side where your cardinality is >1 (in this case, the "server").

My approach would be structured something like...

*`# server.py :`*

```
    import zmq
    from multiprocessing import Process

    class Producer (Process):
    
      def init(self):
        ...
    
      def run(self):
        ctx = zmq.Context(1)
        sock = zmq.Socket(ctx, zmq.PUB)
        # Multiple producers, so connect instead of bind (consumer must bind)
        sock.connect('ipc://test')
        while True:
          ...
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
      producer = Producer()
      p = Process(target=producer.run)
      p.start()
      p.join()
```

---

*`# client.py :`*

```
    import zmq

    ctx = zmq.Context(1)
    sock = zmq.Socket(ctx, zmq.SUB)
    # Capture from multiple producers, so bind (producers must connect)
    sock.bind('ipc://test')
    sock.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '') 
    while True:
      print(sock.recv())
```

Comment: Sorry, **this will never fly** - your promise to create a working solution *"within each subprocess" is wrong and **will fail*** on colliding into the already owned resource ( each  subsequent `.bind()` will reject to complete successfully, once 1st succeeds to own the address ).

Comment: You are correct; I overlooked the bind/connect direction in my focus on the context and socket. I will update my answer.